# Value connection of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, json

```
 String url = Config.DATA_URL+TempItem.toString().trim();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                showJSON(response);
            }
        },
```

This is the constructor where I parse in my response.
I am a total beginner in android studio and I have no idea how to solve this error. I have read other forums which I tried implementing to no avail. My JSON result is

```
"result":[  
      {  
         "BusinessName":"KachangPuteh",
         "AmountTotal":"100‌​",
         "RequiredTotal":"2‌​00",
         "MaxTotal":"500"         ‌​
      }
   ]
}






private void showJSON(String response){
        String name="";
        String AmountTotal="";
        String RequiredTotal = "";
        String MaxTotal = "";
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
          String results= jsonObject.getString(Config.JSON_ARRAY);

            JSONArray result = new JSONArray(results);


            JSONObject stallsData = result.getJSONObject(0);
            name = stallsData.getString(Config.KEY_NAME);
            AmountTotal = stallsData.getString(Config.KEY_AmountTotal);
            MaxTotal = stallsData.getString(Config.KEY_MT);
            RequiredTotal = stallsData.getString(Config.KEY_RT);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("error ",e.getMessage());
        }

        Stall.setText("Name:\t"+name+"\nAmountTotal:\t" +AmountTotal+ "\nMaxTotal:\t"+ MaxTotal);
    }
```

This is to change my JSONObject to JSONArray.

Edit:
This is my php file

```
<?php 


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){

 $id  = $_GET['id'];

 require_once('conn.php');

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM business WHERE BusinessID='".$id."'";

 $r = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

 $res = mysqli_fetch_array($r);

 $result = array();

 array_push($result,array(
 "BusinessName"=>$res["BusinessName"],
 "AmountTotal"=>$res["AmountTotal"],
 "RequiredTotal"=>$res["RequiredTotal"],
"MaxTotal"=>$res["MaxTotal"]



 )

  $str = json_encode(array("result"=>$result)); $str=str_replace('&#8203;','',$str); $str=str_replace('&zwnj;','',$str); echo $srt;
 echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
 );


 mysqli_close($conn);

}
```

this is my config file.

```
public class Config {
    public static final String DATA_URL = "http://192.168.1.2/retrieveone.php?id=";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "BusinessName";
    public static final String KEY_AmountTotal = "AmountTotal";
    public static final String KEY_RT = "RequiredTotal";
    public static final String KEY_MT = "MaxTotal";
    public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are parsing data wrongly. Try below code -

```
JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
JSONObject stallsData = result.getJSONObject(0);
```

Comment: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject This error came out instead

Comment: Can you make sure, in a response you are not getting html tags.

Comment: how do I get about it? Would be helpful if codes are provided

Comment: If possible send me an url of request

Comment: have added my php at the top

Answer (score 0):

- Here i am doing some changes in your code .

  {"result":[
       {
          "BusinessName":"KachangPuteh",
          "AmountTotal":"100‌​",
          "RequiredTotal":"2‌​00",
          "MaxTotal":"500"         ‌​
       }    ] }

this will be your actual response.

now i am going to parse it.

` private void showJSON(String response){

String name="";

String AmountTotal="";

String RequiredTotal = "";

String MaxTotal = "";

try {

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
```

JSONArray  result = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");  // this line is new

```
        for(int i=0;i<result.length;i++){
           JSONObject stallsData = result.getJSONObject(i);
           name = stallsData.getString(Config.KEY_NAME);
           AmountTotal = stallsData.getString(Config.KEY_AmountTotal);
           MaxTotal = stallsData.getString(Config.KEY_MT);
           RequiredTotal = stallsData.getString(Config.KEY_RT);
       } catch (JSONException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           Log.e("error ",e.getMessage());
       }
```

}Stall.setText("Name:\t"+name+"\nAmountTotal:\t" +AmountTotal+ "\nMaxTotal:\t"+ MaxTotal);
       }

Comment: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject This error came out instead How do I do it ? Would be helpful if codes can be provided

Comment: I think you are getting improper response try to request your url on post man than you can check what you are getting exact.

Answer (score 0):

you can write

```
try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray loginNodes = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        for (int i = 0; i < loginNodes.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jo = loginNodes.getJSONObject(i);

                           String BusinessName= jo.getString("BusinessName");
                           String AmountTotal= jo.getString("AmountTotal");
                           String RequiredTotal= jo.getString("RequiredTotal");
                           String MaxTotal= jo.getString("MaxTotal");


                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Comment: Can you tell me details. do you feel any problem till